# How to control the SQL limit

Tags: php

I would like to know how to print 100 records then an image and then another 100 records.

I am trying to use the following code in order to control the sql limit, but would like to know how to do the above in the proper way.

**Total number of records are x numbers**

```
$check_starts=0;
$check_ends=100;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names limit $check_starts,$check_ends")
or die(mysql_error());
```

i would like to know how to print 100 records in in every interval.

then I need a break after every 100 records.

thanks for your help.

Comment: are you referring to pagination? in which case `LIMIT 0, 100` and the next time `LIMIT 100, 200` and so on... There are plenty of 
"pagination class" scripts that other have wrote that you can use. Just google for them.

Comment: Be aware that there are a lot of better approaches to this problem to consider, for example:
== As mentioned below, start out the right way and use PDO or mysqli to avoid compromising your database with sql injection.
== In addition to that, use a templating engine to keep your html separate from your php!  As a new coder, it'll let you learn a better approach of separation.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** Please use [`PDO`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `Mysql`.

To address your question, you aren't going to want to use the `LIMIT` clause.  I assume you want to retrieve *all* records, right?  The `LIMIT` clause is only for retrieving a certain subset of records.

Instead, as you're fetching each record, keep track of the number.  Every 100 records, print an image:

```
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($i % 100 === 0) {
        // print the image
    }

    ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question, but are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 100;
$r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names");
$total = mysql_result($r,0);
while ( $start <= $total )
{
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names limit $start, $limit");
  while ( $d = mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
  {
    /* Do whatever */
  }
  /* Print image */
  $start += $limit;
}
```

Comment: Actually the solution provided by drrck.. is better. As you were talking about LIMIT I stuck with your idea but it's better done without it, just with $i % 100.